# Login function upgrading from zend framework 1 to zf2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the following function in ZF1 login controller and works fine but cannot port to ZF2 please help me this function to work with zf2

```
if ($this->_request->isPost() && $userForm->isValid($_POST)) {
        $data = $userForm->getValues();

    //set up the auth adapter
    // get the default db adapter
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    //create the auth adapter
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'users','username', 'password');

    //set the username and password
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['username']);
    $authAdapter->setCredential(md5($data['password']));

    //authenticate
    $result = $authAdapter->authenticate();
    if ($result->isValid()) {

        // store the username, first and last names of the user
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $storage = $auth->getStorage();
        $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(
            array('username' , 'first_name' , 'last_name', 'role')));

        return $this->_forward('index');
    } else {
        $this->view->loginMessage = "Sorry, your username or
            password was incorrect";
    }
}
$this->view->form = $userForm;`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way in ZF2 is to use the [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) module for user login and registration.

Alternatively, you need to refactor to use the new [`Zend\Db`](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.db.html) component which has a very different API from `Zend_Db`. 
Unfortunately, as of ZF2 beta 3, `Zend\Auth` hasn't yet been updated to use the new `Zend\Db` component, so you'll need to rework it considerably or wait until a later release. Also, note that ZF2 uses namespaces, so you'll need to refactor for that at least.